# why gdal gave me different max and min values of a variable from R?

Tags: r, gdal, netcdf, rgdal

These three lines will open and read one variable from a netcdf file:

```
f=open.ncdf("C:\\BR_Ji1.nc")
A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="date",verbose=TRUE)
B = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="GPP",verbose=TRUE)
[1] "get.var.ncdf: entering. Here is varid:"
[1] "GPP"                 
[1] "checking to see if passed varid is actually a dimvar"
[1] "entering vobjtodimname with varid= GPP"
[1] "vobjtodimname: is a character type varid.  This file has 6 dims"
[1] "vobjtodimname: no cases found, returning FALSE"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: isdimvar: FALSE"
[1] "vobjtovarid: entering with varid=GPP"
[1] "Variable named GPP found in file with varid= 17"
[1] "vobjtovarid: returning with varid deduced from name; varid= 17"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: ending up using varid= 17"
[1] "ndims: 2"            
[1] "get.var.ncdf: varsize:" 
[1]     1 17520          
[1] "get.var.ncdf: start:" 
[1] 1 1                     
[1] "get.var.ncdf: count:"
[1]     1 17520            
[1] "get.var.ncdf: totvarsize: 17520"
[1] "Getting var of type 3  (1=short, 2=int, 3=float, 4=double, 5=char, 6=byte)"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: C call returned 0"
[1] "count.nodegen: 17520    Length of data: 17520"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: final dims of returned array:"
[1] 17520       
[1] "varid: 17" 
[1] "nc$varid2Rindex: 1"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 2"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 0"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 0"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 3" 
[6] "nc$varid2Rindex: 0"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 4"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 5"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 6"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 7" 
[11] "nc$varid2Rindex: 8"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 9"  "nc$varid2Rindex: 10" "nc$varid2Rindex: 11" "nc$varid2Rindex: 12" 
[16] "nc$varid2Rindex: 13" "nc$varid2Rindex: 14" "nc$varid2Rindex: 15" "nc$varid2Rindex: 16" "nc$varid2Rindex: 17"
[21] "nc$varid2Rindex: 18" "nc$varid2Rindex: 19" "nc$varid2Rindex: 20"
[1] "nc$varid2Rindex[varid]: 14"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: setting missing values to NA"
[1] "missval: -9999   tol: 0.09999"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: implementing add_offset ( FALSE ) and scale_factor ( FALSE )"
[1] "var has NEITHER add_offset nor scale_factor"
**K = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="Qle",verbose=TRUE)
write.table(t(rbind(A,B,K)),"C:\\Ji1-gpp-lat.txt")**
```

When I looked at the extracted data I found that I have very small and negative values.
Then I used gdalinfo and found that the max is 400 and min is 0 (which is normal and this is how the values should look like). Any ideas why I am getting the number wrongly?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a display problem? If `gdalinfo` formats numbers as integers, for example, negative numbers of miniscule magnitude will be displayed as `0`

Comment: Re-do `gdalinfo` with `-stats` to force regeneration of statistics. What did `R` report? Another good tool that you can use, if you know Python/NumPy, is [netcdf4-python](http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/).

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Does ComputeBandStats take nodata into account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857254). The statistics contained in the file's metadata may not be fresh or precisely calculated. If you want accurate statistics you should calculate them yourself, or make sure the flag for calculating them using approximations is set to False.